# Import subset of a MySql dumpo

Tags: mysql

I have a database dump, let's say db.sql, that I have to import in MySql

I do not want to import all the tables in the dump but only the ones whose name start with a certain subset of letters (for example p-z)

I can grep somehow the text of the db.sql file but I am wondering if someone has a better solution for that.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dump files are almost plaintext files with DDL/DML operations. Hence, the easiest would be to read the dump file, select relevant operations and write to another file and import it into mysql. So, you already have the best solution as far as I can think.